# Rails - Used LEFT OUTER JOIN in Controller, and now my Link_to's in the view don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller I put:
`@ds = Sir.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM Sirs LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees ON Sirs.input_id = Employees.id")`

In my view I put:

```
<% @ds.each do |sir| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= sir.name %></td>
    <td><%= sir.problem %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', sir %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sir_path(sir) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', sir, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Now I get the following error:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sirs", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason here is exactly your using outer join.

Try doing `SELECT * FROM Sirs LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees ON Sirs.input_id = Employees.id` from the SQL console, and most certainly it will yield the rowset with actually two id fields: one from the Sirs table and another from Employees. And rightly so, as this is how left outer join works.

A quick fix might be to change it to:

```
SELECT Sirs.* FROM Sirs LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees ON Sirs.input_id = Employees.id
```

This should eliminate fields coming from the Employees table.

As a more generic fix I would recommend sticking more to ActiveRecord logic for the cases where it is possible. I hate doing it myself, but ActiveRecord sometimes requires fields to be named in a magical way, especially when doing eager loading and joins, so that it can perform optimizations. Writing SQL on your own might lead to subtle bugs and/or future incompatibilities. That is besides it being non-railsish.

Comment: But if you think about it `SELECT Sirs.* FROM Sirs LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees ON Sirs.input_id = Employees.id` is the very equivalent of just `SELECT * FROM Sirs`. So whatever the reason was for the JOIN, it isn't actually doing anything useful in this case.

Comment: OK got it. - I just had to list the columns I wanted, and leave out the Employees.id column. Having one .id column is enough!

Comment: Nice trick! Glad it worked. Would you mind accepting the answer then?